# How to count certain values without using "lists" in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am supposed to complete this function without using lists and I am not sure how to go about doing so. If I could get some pointers or help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
def uniqueDigitsFound(secretString, guess):
"""
Return the number of digits that are contained in both the secretString
and the guess. For example when secretString is 12345 and guess is 67821,
the two strings, share two digits: 1 and 2.
uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "67890")  returns 0
uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "21435") returns 5
"""
# Make sub to not contain duplicates in guess so
# guess only has unique digits, and length of 1 to 5
# TODO: Complete this function







# Test uniqueDigitsFound.
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "44444") == 1)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "44424") == 2)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "00000") == 0)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "00100") == 1)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "01050") == 2)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "01350") == 3)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "21350") == 4)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "21354") == 5)
```

Comment: a = list(set([char for char in secretString])), b = list(set([char for char in guess])), result = sum([1 for i in b if i in b ])

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant of solution:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldBBCsIwEAXQfU4xRJAGijRJuxG6Ey@gFxA71oCkmkwWnj6mtEWkm/iXw3/JMM833QerY@zwBsGaV8CD6Q354xBsV3i8OqQTOWP7EvqA3os9g5Q0Ds7CA20q0U9RwBbG2VQXjLENnNHT@v0du3iPjor1z1wqXTe8BF6P4QLaFqTIBGoGKgtUYyZQZQK5gLyVUr@p/lpJ6gXoLKC@oM4G85UawWL8AA)

```
def uniqueDigitsFound(secretString, guess):
    return len(set(secretString) & set(guess))


# Test uniqueDigitsFound.
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "44444") == 1)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "44424") == 2)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "00000") == 0)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "00100") == 1)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "01050") == 2)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "01350") == 3)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "21350") == 4)
assert(uniqueDigitsFound("12345", "21354") == 5)
```